# 画面遷移を伴うスクレイピングで取得したデータをCSVファイルに出力したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, web-scraping, nokogiri

**環境**

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1
macOS

**前提**

ポートフォリオ作成のため、現在自作アプリを実装しております。
その中で、DBに必要なデータを保存するため、Rubyのnokogiriでスクレイピングを行なっています。

以前、スクレイピングについて質問させていただき、取得したデータをDBに保存することができたのですが、スクレイピング先のサイトの変更があったため、CSVに出力してデータを保持した方が良いと感じ、現在取り組んでいます。

**解決したいこと**

取得したデータをCSVファイルに出力したいです。

**試したこと**

CSV出力に関する参考記事を元にコードを修正し、コンソールで実行した所、繰り返し処理がうまく行われておらず、最初の1件しかデータを取得することができていませんでした（下記）

`db/csv_data/spot_list.csv`

```
"name","time","location","feature","image","url","latitude","longitude"
"兵庫県立フラワーセンターのサルビア","6月下旬〜8月下旬","兵庫県加西市豊倉町飯森1282−1 兵庫県立フラワーセンター","園内中央には豊かな水に水鳥が遊ぶ亀の倉池を配し、背に野鳥のつどう緑濃い飯盛山を取り込んだ、約46haにおよぶ松の自然林をそのままに生す全国でも有数の花の公園。池を巡る遊歩道を歩けば、季節の花が咲き競う四季の花壇、大温室、花と彫刻の道、かおりの森など、約4,500種類の花々が咲く。園内の中央にある亀の倉池の近くには大小さまざまな花壇が展開。中央花壇、四季の花壇、池辺の花壇等合わせて12,000㎡の花壇は、春にはチューリップ、夏から秋にはサルビア、マリーゴールド、ベゴニア・センパフローレンス、菊、冬はパンジー、ハボタンなどで埋めつくされる。4月の春からは460品種22万本のチューリップが次々と開花します。","https://image-loconavi.tokubai.co.jp/w=400,h=400,a=2/uploads/spot/placard/image/40430/ac27a2ba-3576-4b9b-bf3c-2bac4089cbe6.jpg","http://www.hyogo-park.or.jp/flower-center/","34.907757","134.859368"
```

byebugでモデル内のデバックしながらファイルの書き込み部分のコードを変更させるなど色々試してみたのですが、解決には至っておりません。

詳しい方がいましたら是非アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

**該当するソースコード**

`db/schema.rb`

```
  create_table "spots", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "time"
    t.string "location"
    t.text "feature"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "url"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.integer "area_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["area_id"], name: "index_spots_on_area_id"
  end
```

`app/models/scraping.rb`

```
class Scraping < ApplicationRecord
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'csv'

  def self.spot_list_scrape
    base_url = 'https://loconavi.jp/'
    features_url = 'features/hananomeisho'
    url = "#{base_url}#{features_url}"

    # google mapsの正規表現、緯度・経度をキャプチャする
    maps_regexp = /\Ahttp:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/\?q=(.+),(.+)\z/

    # テーブルヘッダーの作成
    header = ['name', 'time', 'location', 'feature', 'image', 'url', 'latitude', 'longitude']
    rows = []
    rows << header

    # timesメソッドを使用して20回ループさせる
    20.times do |i|
      html = URI.open(url).read
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

　　     # # 該当クラスが存在しない場合、ループを終了させる
      if doc.css('.flower')[i] == nil
        break
      end

      # _[i]_はtimesメソッドの変数で、繰り返すことに1づつ数値が増えていく
      flower_href = doc.css('.flower')[i]["href"]

      # 相対URL(flower_href)と結合させて絶対URLを作成
      next_url = "#{base_url}#{flower_href}"

      3.times do |i|
        html = URI.open(next_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

        # 該当クラスが存在しない場合、次のループに移行
        if doc.css('.flower-spot')[i] == nil
          next
        end

        href = doc.css('.flower-spot')[i]["href"]
        link_url = "#{base_url}#{href}"

        html = URI.open(link_url).read
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

        doc.css('.main-left-layout').each do | node |
          latitude, longitude = nil, nil
          node.css("a").each do |node|
            # aタグを絞り込み正規表現にマッチするリンクを探す
            result = maps_regexp.match(node[:href])

            # アンマッチの場合、次の要素に移行
            if result.nil?
              next
            end

            # match:マッチ全体 latitude:緯度 longitude:経度
            match, latitude, longitude = result.to_a
          end

          # データが取得できなかった場合、次のループに移行
          if node.at_css('.block') == nil \
            || node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1] == nil \
            || node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1] == nil \
            || node.at_css('.text') == nil \
            || node.at_css('img') == nil \
            || node.at_css('#information p a') == nil
            next
          end

          # 各カラムのデータを取得
          name = node.at_css('.block').inner_text
          time = node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1].inner_text
          location = node.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1].inner_text
          feature = node.at_css('.text').inner_text
          image = node.at_css('img').attribute('src').value
          url = node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]
          latitude = latitude
          longitude = longitude

          rows << [name, time, location, feature, image, url, latitude, longitude]
        end
      end
    end
    # CSVに書き込み
    CSV.open('db/csv_data/spot_list.csv', 'w', :force_quotes=>true) do |csv|
      rows.each do |row|
        csv << row
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: 「データが取得できなかった場合、次のループに移行」で、`node.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1]` が nil になる場合がある事が原因です。

Comment: 回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
指摘いただいた箇所についてですが、データが取得できずnilになる場合があるため、nextを使用して次のループに移行するよう記述した次第です。
以前作成したメソッド(DB保存用)を試してみた所、無事データを取得できていました。CSVでのデータ保存だとこの記述方法では機能しないのでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、それで本当の原因が判りました。トップレベルの `20.times do ...` の直後で `html = URI.open(url).read` としていますが、この `url` 変数が `url = node.at_css('#information p a')["href"]` の部分で書き換えられしまっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントに書いた通り、`url` 変数の上書きが原因かと思います。

以下は本題からは離れた話になります。

> データが取得できずnilになる場合があるため、nextを使用して次のループに移行するよう記述した次第です。

この部分の判定処理に関しては Ruby 2.3.0 で導入された [Safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) を使うと簡潔に記述できます。

例えば以下の処理では `NoMethodError`(exception)が発生しますが、

```rb
nil[0]

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

Safe navigation operator を使うと exception は発生しません。

```rb
nil&.[](0)
=> nil
```

以下は `Scraping.spot_list_scrape` メソッドを取り出して書き変えたコードです。参考にしてみてください。

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

BASE_URL = 'https://loconavi.jp'
FEATURES_URL = '/features/hananomeisho'

# google mapsの正規表現、緯度・経度をキャプチャする
MAPS_REGEXP = /\Ahttp:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/\?q=(.+),(.+)\z/

# テーブルヘッダーの作成
header = ['name', 'time', 'location', 'feature', 'image', 'url', 'latitude', 'longitude']
rows = [header]

# scraping
html = URI.open(BASE_URL + FEATURES_URL).read
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

doc.css('.flower').each{|flower|
  html = URI.open(BASE_URL + flower['href']).read
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

  doc.css('.flower-spot')[0..3].each{|spot|
    html = URI.open(BASE_URL + spot['href']).read
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

    doc.css('.main-left-layout').each {|main|
      coords = main.css('a').each{|a|
        c = MAPS_REGEXP.match(a[:href])
        break c.to_a[1..2] unless c.nil?
      }
      next if coords.nil?

      # 各カラムのデータを取得
      name = main.at_css('.block')&.inner_text
      time = main.css('.spot-info > .t-cell')[1]&.inner_text
      location = main.css('.spot-info > .t-row > .t-cell')[1]&.inner_text
      feature = main.at_css('.text')&.inner_text
      image = main.at_css('img')&.attribute('src')&.value
      url = main.at_css('#information p a')&.[](:href)

      # 全てのデータが取得できれば CSV へ追加
      row = [name, time, location, feature, image, url]
      rows << row + coords if row.all?
    }
  }
}

# CSVに書き込み
CSV.open('spot_list.csv', 'w', :force_quotes=>true) do |csv|
  rows.each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

**取得結果**

|  | name | time | location | feature | image | url | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 兵庫県立フラワーセンターのサルビア | 6月下旬〜8月下旬 | 兵庫県加西市豊倉町飯森1282−1 兵庫県立フラワーセンター | 園内中央には豊かな水に水鳥が遊ぶ亀の倉池... | [image] | http://www.hyogo-park.or.jp/flower-center/ | 34.9078 | 134.859 |
| 2 | 千秋公園の蓮 | 7月上旬～8月中旬 | 秋田県秋田市千秋公園1 | 267年続いた秋田藩20万石・佐竹氏の居... | [image] | http://www.city.akita.akita.jp/city/ur/pc/sensyukouen/default.htm | 39.7229 | 140.124 |
| 3 | ひまわりガーデン武蔵村山 | 7月中旬〜8月中旬 | 東京都武蔵村山市緑が丘１４６０ ひまわりガーデン武蔵村山 | 村山団地北西部の「ひまわりガーデン武蔵村... | [image] | http://www.city.musashimurayama.lg.jp/kankou/spots/himawari/1001598.html | 35.7466 | 139.407 |
| 4 | サンテパルクたはらのひまわり | 7月中旬〜8月中旬 | 愛知県田原市野田町芦ヶ池8 サンテパルクたはら | 愛知県田原市の農業をテーマにした体験型テ... | [image] | http://www.santepark.com | 34.6428 | 137.201 |
| 5 | 第1なぎさ公園のひまわり | 7月中旬〜8月中旬 | 滋賀県守山市今浜町 第1なぎさ公園 | 琵琶湖の東岸にある自然公園の第1なぎさ公... | [image] | https://www.moriyamayamamori.jp/spot/329 | 35.1268 | 135.95 |
| 6 | 三ツ石山の紅葉 | 9月中旬 | 岩手県岩手郡雫石町（その他） 県道212号線 | 東北百名山に選ばれている三ツ石山の紅葉は... | [image] | http://shizukuishi-kanko.gr.jp/ | 39.8515 | 140.896 |
| 7 | 能取湖の紅葉 | 9月上旬〜9月下旬 | 北海道網走市卯原内60-3 能取湖サンゴ草群生地 | 能取湖に広がるサンゴ草の紅葉網走市にある... | [image] | http://abashiri.jp/tabinavi/index.html | 44.0136 | 144.116 |
| 8 | 大雪山(黒岳)の紅葉 | 9月中旬～9月下旬 | 北海道上川郡上川町層雲峡6 | 北海道上川郡上川町 大雪山(黒岳)の紅葉... | [image] | http://www.town.kamikawa.hokkaido.jp | 43.7111 | 142.94 |
| 9 | 十勝岳温泉郷の紅葉 | 9月中旬～9月下旬 | 北海道空知郡上富良野町十勝岳温泉 | 上富良野町にある十勝岳温泉郷の紅葉は例年... | [image] | http://kamifurano.jp | 43.4136 | 142.643 |
| 10 | 滋賀農業公園ブルーメの丘のバラ | 5月下旬～8月中旬 | 滋賀県蒲生郡日野町西大路843 | ドイツ・バイエルン地方の農村を再現した観... | [image] | http://www.blumenooka.jp | 35.0142 | 136.28 |
| 11 | イングリッシュローズガーデン | 6月〜9月 | 長野県北佐久郡軽井沢町長倉 軽井沢タリアセン | バラの育種家として著名なデイビッド・オー... | [image] | http://www.karuizawataliesin.com/ | 36.3284 | 138.597 |
| 12 | タングラム斑尾のラベンダー園 | 7月上旬～8月中旬 | 長野県上水内郡信濃町古海 タングラム斑尾 ラベンダー園 | 長野県上水内郡信濃町にある「タングラム斑... | [image] | https://www.tangram.jp/index.php | 36.8537 | 138.263 |
| 13 | かんのファームのラベンダー | 6月中旬〜10月上旬 | 北海道空知郡上富良野町西12線北36号 | 上富良野町と美瑛町の境界、美馬牛峠で花と... | [image] | http://www.kanno-farm.com/ | 43.5429 | 142.439 |